# Cleaning up table output in sage

Tags: python, formatting, sage

As the title suggests, I am trying to change the look of my output in Sage while it is formatted as a table. For a smaller amount of data, it looks fine, e.g.

[image]

However, once the right columns have too much data, it overflows like so:

[image]

As you can see, not only do the line breaks seem to go haywire, but also the right column can overflow into the left, making the data appear incorrectly. How might I reformat the latter scenario so that it appears as in the first example? Thank you in advance for any and all help!

**EDIT**

This is what I’m using right now:

```
dictionary_right_sets = dict(...)

my_table = table([dictionary_right_sets.keys(), dictionary_right_sets.values()],
                 frame=True,
                 header_column=['Right set', 'Element(s) whose right set is contained in this right set'])
result_table = my_table.transpose()
print result_table
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Give a code sample.

Comment: my_table = table([dictionary_right_sets.keys(), dictionary_right_sets.values()], frame = True, header_column=['Right set','Element(s) whose right set is contained in this right set']);


result_table = my_table.transpose();


print result_table;

This is what I'm using right now^

Comment: And, what is the `table` function/class? Which library?

Comment: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/misc/sage/misc/table.html

Comment: Hopefully, this is answers your question! Thanks for helping so far.

Comment: If you are using Sage from the command-line, then there should be no problem: the table should be printed as several (very long) lines, but with line breaks in the right spots. (Edit: line about notebook deleted; see answer below.) If all else fails, you can do `s = str(result_table)` and then write `s` to a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using one of the notebook interfaces (either Jupyter or SageNB), try just evaluating `result_table` rather than `print result_table`. Does that give you what you want?

Comment: I feel like a doofus for not figuring this out, but yes! Thank you, John.